# Printing (get a printout) the elements in an arraylist

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, printing, apache-poi

Scenario:

I am doing a small application to extract a huge number of excel sheet data and sort it then save it and then if need print it. I am using `JavaFX for UI and Apache POI` for read and write Excel data. I have put my extracted data to an ArrayList and from that I can do the saving part.

First I thought to put the Arraylist elements into TextArea and then I can print it. But appending each element to a TextArea take a  lot of time (Considering about 100 000 cell data). S I thought to print straight from the ArrayList.

Question:
Is it possible to take a print from an Array list. 
Any of the following options are possible?

This code can be used to print something from the UI like the TextArea.

```
if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(ProjectNavigation.scene.getWindow())){
            boolean success = job.printPage(node);
            if (success) {
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
```

But the question is I don't have the data in my UI. Options I thought:

- Create a temp file and print it the delete the file
- Convert the array list into something and then print it.
- Any library for do that??

Any suggestions will help. Thank you.

PS:

As Khaled Khnifer Mentioned in he answer I used a ListView to show the items in the UI where I can get the data to print.

Comment: Where do you want to print the ArrayList into? JavaFX UI, HTML, File, Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quit sure what you really need here, but I'm going to answer the part where you wanted to print the `ArrayList` into a `TextArea`.

If you are building a **JavaFX** application, you can bind the `ListView` to `ObservableList` which update on changes.

```
public class AppController implements Initializable
{
    @FXML private Button myButton;

    @FXML private ListView myListView;

    // ObservableList is a List
    protected ObservableList<String> list = new FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    protected int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        myListView.setItems(list);

        myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {@Override public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            list.add(counter++);
        }});
    }
}
```

In this example, clicking the button should add a new item to the `ObservableList` the changes will appear on the `ListView` on the screen.

You can add a new item, remove an item, sort the items, modify an item, and the changes will update on the screen.

It's a good way to seperate data from view, you don't need to read data from the UI, write it to the UI, and you can write the data to a file easily since it's `Serializable`.

Comment: Thank you. But I already have a Filled ArrayList. What I need is a way to make a print out of the stuff in the ArrayList. I am looking for the best option.

Comment: @AnjulaRanasinghe `Print the stuff in the ArrayList` to where?

Comment: Thank you 'ListView' Worked. It solved my problem. I think no I can use it to make a printjob. Thanks.

Comment: How does the `ObservableList` know to report changes made to the backing list directly? Pretty sure it can't. Isn't it better to add items through the ObservableList instead?